# admin panel codec with header sidebar and content

Tags: css, css-float, codec, sidebar

hi everyone i need to codec admin panel
for new cms.

**there are 3 main divs.**

`header` which is not fixed.

`sidebar` that is on the right side of the screen

`content` that is on the right of the sidebar

**here is picture to describe the issue:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLKN7.png

how should i do it?

i am kind of lost

well i tried to do something like this:

```
#main { height: 100%; } 
#header { width: 100%; height: 43px; position:absolute; z-index: 2; } 
#layer2 { position: absolute; z-index: 1; width: 100%; float: right; margin-top: 43px; } 
#content { margin-right: 224px; } 
#sidebar { float: right; width: 224px; min-height: 100%; margin-right: -100%; }
```

and html:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="header>HEADER</div>
    <div id="layer2">
        <div id="content">
            content
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar">
            sidebar
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use content{float:left;} and sidebar{float:right;}

Comment: i edit my post you can see what i tried to do

Comment: @user1563236 [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/zrE5V/)?

Comment: @Vucko i want it to be responsive thats the problem. i can do something simple with float left and right thats not the issue

Comment: @user1563236 if you're looking for responsive , I'd recommend you to use [media querys](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/).